# django - how to get all the projects for a team?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am new to Django and have a question I couldn't solve it by myself. It is a big question for me.

I want to show the list of **Projects** related to a specific **Team** and show it in a ListView.

I would assume it should check the current user belong to which team and then based on the team, it should list the projects.

I have a two apps in my project: 1) users and 2)projects

users.models:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser 
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model 
from django.urls import reverse 


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    bio= models.CharField(max_length=300, null= True, blank=True)


class Team (models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user= models.ManyToManyField(get_user_model())
    date_created= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    date_updated= models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,blank=True, null=True )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):  
        return reverse('team_detail', args=[str(self.pk)])
```

and the project model is

```
class Project (models.Model):
    team= models.ForeignKey(Team,on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False, blank=False)
    notes = models.TextField( null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('project_detail', args=[str(self.pk)])
```

in projects.views: I made the following codes but cant work out the queryset between two models.

```
class ProjectPageView(ListView):
    model = Project

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(ProjectPageView, self).get_queryset()
        queryset = queryset.filter( XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX )
        return queryset

    context_object_name = 'projects_list'
    template_name = 'projects/projects.html'
```

and in the HTML

```
{% extends '_base.html' %}

{% block title %}Projects{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}

 <h1> Project list for this Team : </h1>
  {% for project in project_list %}
      <div>
        <h5><a href="{{ project.get_absolute_url }}">{{ project.title }}</a></h5>


      </div>
  {% endfor %}



{% endblock content %}
```

Really really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the current user from the request object, then proceed

```
class ProjectPageView(ListView):
    model = Project

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(ProjectPageView, self).get_queryset()
        user_team = Team.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).first()
        queryset = queryset.filter(team=user_team)
        return queryset

    context_object_name = 'projects_list'
    template_name = 'projects/projects.html'
```

Comment: Great - thanks for solving my biggest django problem so far!

Comment: I think you can use this form also `filter(team__user-self.request.user)`.